# Get Decision Tree Prediction With Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-trees

If I give random forest parameters as

```
RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,bootstrap=False,max_features=None,random_state=2019)
```

Should it be creating 10 same decision trees?
But it is not. 
I am asking the random forest to

1. Sample without replacement (bootstrap=False) and each tree have same number of sample (ie the total data )(verified using plot)
2. Select all features in all trees.

But `model.estimators_[2]` and `model.estimators_[5]` are different